# How can I make a conveyor belt FBX that spins without rigging?

Tags: modeling

I tried rigging, doesnt work. I tried exporting it with curve unapplied, doesnt work. What WILL work? I am grappling for help right now, Ive looked at everything. Please help me, I need help.

I have a conveyor belt with a curve modifier unapplied. I move a cube and the tracks roll. the object doesnt actually move. I have tried rigging it with bones because i thought there was no other answer and spent 3 days on tutorials and 8 days total on this issue. I import it to unity, and it suddenly isnt rolling, but translating. It just moves, because the curve rolls in blender when i move it, but in unity it just moves the whole thing. I need help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the belt "spin" without any rigging, I'd suggest **animating** the **texture** **offset** of the material applied to only the belt inside of Unity. 
This will give the illusion of the belt "spinnig"
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTextureOffset.html

Just increase the x or y offset every frame in

```
void Update ()
```

And make sure to multiply the increment by **Time.deltaTime** so the speed is consistent across all framerates

Comment: please try to keep your answers blender related.

Comment: Yeah I know. He just specifically mentioned unity as a program he was using

Comment: any other ways to do this? unity doesn't support Bézier curves..

Comment: Any program "supports" bezier curves, you just have to code them yourself. Have a look at mega shapes in the asset store